# Getting a list of processes in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net

As the title implies, is there any way I could do this?

I'm trying to do this in an .aspx, this is my current code:

```
    <script runat="server">
    //using System.Diagnostics;
    Process[] processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();


    foreach(Process process in processes)
    {
        lbl = process.MainWindowTitle;
    }
</script>
```

But it's saying foreach isn't a valid token.

Comment: I'm assuming by the tags you mean ASP.NET? The title is misleading. Also, assuming C#? Furthermore, *which* processes? ALL processes? Or just server processes?

Comment: See [`Process.GetProcesses();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx)

Comment: I'm trying to do this in a .aspx web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like everyone else said Process.GetProcesses()

If you use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) you can run this in Statements mode to see how it works and play with it.

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(Process process in processes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(process.ProcessName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET, you can call [`System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx) to retrieve an array of [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccf1tfx0.aspx) objects.

Note that this methods has overloads, and that perhaps one of the overloads may be more suitable to your situation.