# C# Process Start and Stop Service

Tags: c#, windows, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Process Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/c-sharp-process-monitor)

I am trying to write a windows service that detects the Start up and Closing of processes on one of my servers. It seems I can get this information rather easy using Process object if I launch the application myself, but not other processes. It sounds like a very service to write, but have not made any progress.

Comment: You mean like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277620/getting-a-list-of-processes-in-asp-net

Comment: That's horribly expensive and inaccurate.  Use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/c-sharp-process-monitor/1986856#1986856

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use WMI. Make an RPC call to that remote server, authenticate properly, and do a query with WMI to retrieve Processes running.

Comment: Getting the processes running, is not the problem, but detecting when they close is, that is where I am stuck, being unable to detect the process stopping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28VS.85%29.aspx) function to open a process handle for each process currently running.  All you need is the process IDs.  You can then use the process handles in whatever wait function you prefer; they become signaled when the corresponding process exits.

Detecting when a new process is launched is harder.  If polling for new processes is not satisfactory, you'll need to write a device driver and use the [PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559951%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function.